# Python: Create new file and increment the page numbers of existing files with similar names but different page numbers

Tags: python

I can't figure out how to increment the page number of a file that exist with out overwriting its content and creating a new file with the old file name

Example: if i had 4 files called

fileName_1.txt

fileName_2.txt

fileName_3.txt

fileName_4.txt

I would like to increment all their page numbers by 1 and create a new file called fileName_1.txt the problem is that I'm not going to have 5 files in total. Each day I'm going to generate a new file so their should be a counter or something that can help me

Comment: Post your code please. Also, why can't you change the `fileName_4.txt` first?

Answer (score 0):

In general people append timestamp to filenames. Suppose today I write a file `filename.txt`. Tomorrow I would rename `filename.txt` as `filename-18052015.txt` just before creating a new `filename.txt`(with proper error handling).

So the current file, I am writing on would always be `filename.txt`.